# Using keras and tensorflow in R with reticulate to use SVM

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, reticulate

I am able to do svm in R using the `e1071` package. I want to do the same using `tensorflow` through R and keras, but I am a bit lost as to whether this could be done.

```
## let us simulate some two-class data

x  <-  matrix(rnorm(20*2), ncol=2)
class  <- c(rep(-1,10), rep(1,10))
x[class == 1,]  <-  x[class == 1,] + 1


## fit the support vector machine classifier.

training_data  <- data.frame(x = x, class = as.factor(class))

library(e1071)
svmfit  <- svm(class~., 
               data = training_data, 
               kernel = "linear", 
               cost = 10, 
               scale = FALSE)
```

Now, how do I do this in tensorflow, but using the R environment?

```
library(reticulate)
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate") 

library(keras)
install_keras(envname = "r-reticulate")
library(tensorflow)
```

From what I understand, I use the sckikit for the tensorflow library, but how do I call from R?

Inside `python`, I know that there is a module called  `tensorflow.keras.layers` from where we `import SVM` but I can not find a similar layer in the `keras` and `tensorflow` packages in R.

```
names(tf$keras$layers)
 [1] "AbstractRNNCell"        "Activation"             "ActivityRegularization"
  [4] "add"                    "Add"                    "AdditiveAttention"     
  [7] "AlphaDropout"           "Attention"              "average"               
 [10] "Average"                "AveragePooling1D"       "AveragePooling2D"      
 [13] "AveragePooling3D"       "AvgPool1D"              "AvgPool2D"             
 [16] "AvgPool3D"              "BatchNormalization"     "Bidirectional"         
 [19] "CategoryEncoding"       "CenterCrop"             "concatenate"           
 [22] "Concatenate"            "Conv1D"                 "Conv1DTranspose"       
 [25] "Conv2D"                 "Conv2DTranspose"        "Conv3D"                
 [28] "Conv3DTranspose"        "ConvLSTM1D"             "ConvLSTM2D"            
 [31] "ConvLSTM3D"             "Convolution1D"          "Convolution1DTranspose"
 [34] "Convolution2D"          "Convolution2DTranspose" "Convolution3D"         
 [37] "Convolution3DTranspose" "Cropping1D"             "Cropping2D"            
 [40] "Cropping3D"             "Dense"                  "DenseFeatures"         
 [43] "DepthwiseConv1D"        "DepthwiseConv2D"        "deserialize"           
 [46] "Discretization"         "dot"                    "Dot"                   
 [49] "Dropout"                "EinsumDense"            "ELU"                   
 [52] "Embedding"              "experimental"           "Flatten"               
 [55] "GaussianDropout"        "GaussianNoise"          "GlobalAveragePooling1D"
 [58] "GlobalAveragePooling2D" "GlobalAveragePooling3D" "GlobalAvgPool1D"       
 [61] "GlobalAvgPool2D"        "GlobalAvgPool3D"        "GlobalMaxPool1D"       
 [64] "GlobalMaxPool2D"        "GlobalMaxPool3D"        "GlobalMaxPooling1D"    
 [67] "GlobalMaxPooling2D"     "GlobalMaxPooling3D"     "GroupNormalization"    
 [70] "GRU"                    "GRUCell"                "HashedCrossing"        
 [73] "Hashing"                "Identity"               "Input"                 
 [76] "InputLayer"             "InputSpec"              "IntegerLookup"         
 [79] "Lambda"                 "Layer"                  "LayerNormalization"    
 [82] "LeakyReLU"              "LocallyConnected1D"     "LocallyConnected2D"    
 [85] "LSTM"                   "LSTMCell"               "Masking"               
 [88] "maximum"                "Maximum"                "MaxPool1D"             
 [91] "MaxPool2D"              "MaxPool3D"              "MaxPooling1D"          
 [94] "MaxPooling2D"           "MaxPooling3D"           "minimum"               
 [97] "Minimum"                "MultiHeadAttention"     "multiply"              
[100] "Multiply"               "Normalization"          "Permute"               
[103] "PReLU"                  "RandomBrightness"       "RandomContrast"        
[106] "RandomCrop"             "RandomFlip"             "RandomHeight"          
[109] "RandomRotation"         "RandomTranslation"      "RandomWidth"           
[112] "RandomZoom"             "ReLU"                   "RepeatVector"          
[115] "Rescaling"              "Reshape"                "Resizing"              
[118] "RNN"                    "SeparableConv1D"        "SeparableConv2D"       
[121] "SeparableConvolution1D" "SeparableConvolution2D" "serialize"             
[124] "SimpleRNN"              "SimpleRNNCell"          "Softmax"               
[127] "SpatialDropout1D"       "SpatialDropout2D"       "SpatialDropout3D"      
[130] "StackedRNNCells"        "StringLookup"           "subtract"              
[133] "Subtract"               "TextVectorization"      "ThresholdedReLU"       
[136] "TimeDistributed"        "UnitNormalization"      "UpSampling1D"          
[139] "UpSampling2D"           "UpSampling3D"           "Wrapper"               
[142] "ZeroPadding1D"          "ZeroPadding2D"          "ZeroPadding3D"
```

Is there something else to look at, or some other way to do this in R's keras/tensorflow?